# Angular 6: How to update all the property value in localstorage by checking a condition of a property?

Tags: javascript, angular6, local-storage

I have a button addToCart, the value of that gets stored in Localstorage.
I want to update all the incoming values of localstorage, if it satisfies a certain condition.

Here is the function

```js
addToCart(itemValue) {
  console.log("cart value--", itemValue);
  // this.cartProduct = this.getCartProduct(itemValue.productAlias);
  let count = 0;
  var countValue: any;
  let shipPrice = 4.75;
  let result: any = [];
  //  console.log("cart data", this.getCartProduct(itemValue.productAlias));
  var item = {
    userId: this.userId,
    productid: itemValue.productId,
    seller: itemValue.seller,
    price: itemValue.price,
    sellerId: itemValue.sellerId,
    productAlias: itemValue.productAlias,
    productImage: itemValue.productImage,
    productName: itemValue.proName,
    shippingPrice: shipPrice
  };
  if (count > 0) {
    console.log("if condition", count);
    shipPrice = 1.50;
  }
  // console.log("cart value--", item);
  if (localStorage.getItem('cart') == null) {
    this.cart.push(JSON.stringify(item));
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(this.cart));
    // console.log(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
  } else {
    let cart: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    let index: number = -1;
    // let item = JSON.parse(cart);
    console.log("item************" + cart);
 
    for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
      let item = JSON.parse(cart[i]);
      console.log("local storage value", item);
      if (item.productid == itemValue.productId && item.seller == itemValue.seller) {
        index = i;
        break;
      }
      if (item.sellerId == itemValue.sellerId) {
        count++;
        console.log("count-----" + count);
        let item = JSON.parse(cart[i]);
        item.shippingPrice = 1.50;
        cart[i] = JSON.stringify(item);
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
      }



    }


    if (index == -1) {
      // count=0; 
      cart.push(JSON.stringify(item));
      localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
    }

  }
  // let cartValue: any = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
  // console.log("cart value********", cartValue);  
  this.helperSvc.notifySuccess('Product Added to Cart');
  this.router.navigate([`/in/product/${this.pTitle}`]);
}
```

I want that if sellerId is same, the value of shipping price will be 1.50; and if any entry has same sellerid the shipping price will be 1.50,
and for every entry in localstorage the condition must be checked.

here is the local storage cart

`{"userId":"8","productid":"1","seller":"user","price":"100","sellerId":"2","productAlias":"pure-mens-plain-shirt","productImage":"uploads/1562685351.jpg","productName":"Pure Mens Plain Shirt","shippingPrice":4.75},{"userId":"8","productid":"2","seller":"user","price":"50","sellerId":"2","productAlias":"mens-cotton-shirt","productImage":"uploads/1562685440.jpg","productName":"Mens Cotton Shirt","shippingPrice":4.75}`

i want that is any entry in local storage is there and there `sellerid` are  same, the shipping price of same `sellerid` should be updated to 1.50.

Comment: With due respect. I would like to say that this code looks meaningless. Please be clear about what you are asking and post a clear concise and meaningful code sample.

Comment: check now i have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I have still not completely understood your question. But I think you want to check if a particular `sellerId` is present in your JSON array which you get from local storage. So first lets first get the data from `localStorage`:

```
const localStorageValue = localStorage.getItem(yourLocalStorageVar)
```

You will get the JSON array now you need to parse it and check if entry is there

```
const isSameSellerId = JSON.parse(localStorageValue).some(x => x.sellerId === yourSellerId)
```

I have used `some` to check if any particular object in your array has the same `sellerId`.

Now you can do whatever you want to do based on `isSameSellerId`.